# Interpretation of interaction term in Cox regression

Tags: interaction, cox-model, stata

I am trying in Stata to analyze the effect of an exposure on the risk of an event, and to determine whether this risk increases or not after a temporal cut-off.

I have two groups of subjects, with multiple observations per subject. Every observation is in a separate row.

One group keeps being exposed after the cut off and the other one stops being exposed after the cut-off.

The variables are all dummies:

-Event: 0 --> no occurrence; 1 --> occurrence

-Exposure: 0 if the subject is part of the group that keeps being exposed after the cut-off; 1 if the subject is part of the group that stops being exposed after the cut-off

-Time: 0 if the event occurred before the cut-off, 1 if the event occurred after the cut-off.

My dataset is structured as follows:

| ID | Exposure | Event | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I run the stset command in Stata:

```
stset time, fail(event) origin(date_of_birth) exit(time.) id(id) enter(time0) time0(time0)
```

and the following Cox regression command:

```
xi: stcox i.exposure*i.time i.covariate1 i.covariate2 i.covariate3, efron robust nolog cluster(id)
```

I have doubts about the output, that I will simplify below:

| Variable | HAZARD RATIO |
| --- | --- |
| exposure | 0.771 |
| time | 0.179 |
| exposure*time | 1.027 |

My interpretation is the following:

-the group of subjects that stops being exposed has 23% less risk than the group that keeps being exposed
-the risk after the cut-off is 83% smaller than the risk before the cut-off
-and here comes the doubt. How has this HR to be interpreted? After that subjects in group 1 stop being exposed, their risk seem to increase according to this HR. Or do I have to multiply this HR with the HR for the exposure?